# Black space on top of View Controller

Tags: ios, xib, ios11

Since iOS11, i have a black space on the top of my screen :

[image]

My view controller is defined in a Xib file and displayed in a NavigationController

What can i do to remove this top space?

Edit :

The view is defined with a XIB and ViewController is pushed into a navigation controller

Safe Area is disabled
[image]

Comment: The question is *why* there is black space in the first place. How o you add your content below the navigation bar?

Comment: It's just an UIViewController defined with a XIB and push into a navigationController

Comment: This issue is not regarding for iOS 11, so what you using in navigation bar tint color or image? I'll find out solution.

Comment: It's bar tint color :
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.Blue
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

Comment: Okay Great!! Following this link may be it's useful to you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419308/how-to-fix-transparency-of-navigation-bar-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable safe areas, it should help;
[image]

Comment: I have test without Safe Area, it's not solving my issue. I have update my question

Answer (score 1):

Try to change for controller in navigation item "Large Title" mode to "Never". 
For me it's adjust position of tableView.

```
class UINavigationItem {
   var largeTitleDisplayMode: LargeTitleDisplayMode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is regarding iOS 11, I had the same problem. In my root viewController `navigationItem.titleView` was custom `UISearchBar` and seems that searchBar received wrong height. That's why I had this black line in controller, that was recently pushed. Was fixed by setting height to 44 manually.

Maybe this will help you.